# Automating Read More Div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, automation

I'm working on a testimonial format in which the first paragraph is displayed, with the remaining paragraphs contained behind a "Read More" reveal link. See it in action here: http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms-site2/

What I'd like to do is this: rather than manually wrap a div around the Read More paragraphs and place a button link after, I'd like to automate this in jQuery.

Is it possible for jQuery to sniff out the number of paragraphs inside all blockquotes? It'd place a div tag around anything after the 1st paragraph, and follow it with a "read-more" href.

My best to you. Thank you.

---

```
<section class="review">            

    <blockquote>

        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>

            <!-- BEGIN READ MORE -->                
            <div class="review-continued">

            <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor.</p>

            </div>         
            <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More +</a>       
            <!-- END READ MORE -->

    </blockquote>

    <cite>– Dr. John Doe, M.D., Livermore, CA</cite>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('.review blockquote').each(function () {
    $('p:gt(0)', this).hide();
    var paras = this;
    $('a.read-more', this).click(function () {
        $('p:gt(0)', paras).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hqN3v/)**

Comment: This is an excellent start. Can the jQuery place the "Read More" link as well when necessary? I'd rather not have every blockquote contain the link, as some will be short enough not to need it.

Comment: I'm sure it can; I'm just not sure what your criteria for that is.

Comment: If a blockquote has only 1 paragraph, jQuery would edit nothing.

If a blockquote has 2+ paragraphs, jQuery considers all paragraphs after the 1st to be a toggleable section –– and places a "read more" button after them.

All that's missing from your example is placing the link via jQuery, rather than manually including it in all blockquote markup.

Comment: Quite! It works well in the jsfiddle, but doesn't play well in this site test: http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms-j08691/. The review truncates properly, but the Read More button doesn't appear. Is it possible your JS isn't getting along with the scripts immediately following it in http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms-j08691/_/js/functions.js ?

Comment: Possibly. I pasted your code in a fiddle and it seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hqN3v/2/. You may want to try and disable your other plugins/JS to see if that narrows the issue down.

Comment: This is great, but it seems it only affects paragraphs, and no other tags. Is there anyway to include all matter of tags inside the container div, not just `<p>`?